# Multi-language site on different domains

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I need to build a website, available in two languages, behind 2 different domains: language1site.com and language2site.com.

They will both have the same content, but translated in both languages, and the different parts of the theme should be translatable too (preferably via an admin interface).

Would this be possible using a multisite network installation? The whole site-setup would also need to run on a loadbalanced multi-server setup. I've been looking into the WPML plugin, but not sure if they are offering this kind of functionality.

Comment: See the related questions list. We have this covered multiple times.